# Vue transitions when shifting content

Tags: javascript, vue.js, css-transitions, transition

I have run into a problem trying to transition content shifts. Essentially my data array is displayed in different parts of the DOM depending on `state`.

Basic concept:

---

OPEN

- feedback 1  [ complete ]
- feedback 2  [ complete ]
- feedback 3  [ complete ]

CLOSED

---

**What I try to achieve:**
When you press "close", feedback fades out from OPEN and fades in under the CLOSED section

**This is what I tried:** Rendering "Closed" items with a transition:

```
<transition name="fade">
  <v-row v-if="feedbackItem.state ==='closed'" v-for="feedbackItem in closedTasks" :key="feedbackItem.id">
    <p>
    {{ feedbackItem.feedback }}
    </p> 
    </v-row> 
</transition>

<style>
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

But it does not work as needed (no visible transition), and elements under "Closed" are even hidden if there are multiple closed items. I think it has to do with the way the computed item lists are rendered. Possibly the line `v-if="feedbackItem.state ==='closed'"` causes a problem. Does anyone perhaps know how to best achieve the desired result or what am I doing wrong?

Codepen to play around with is [here](https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/wvayzNV).

Thanks for anyone who spares a moment to think along!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing loops you need to use `transition group`:

```
<transition-group name="fade" tag="div">
  <v-row v-if="feedbackItem.state ==='closed'" v-for="feedbackItem in closedTasks" :key="feedbackItem.id">
    <p>
      {{ feedbackItem.feedback }}
    </p> 
  </v-row> 
</transition-group>
```

You can read more [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions).

`tag="div"` is the element that will wrap the list of items.

And just a tip, using `v-if` and `v-for` together is a bad practice. You would be better to have a `computed` property which filters the items you want to loop.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along! If you check the code, I actually did use computed lists to filter out the items,  `v-if`was there since many transitioning examples used that directive to trigger the effect. I followed your suggestion here and removed `v-if` too, but I can't still seem to get it to work. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong? https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/bGdLqWZ

Comment: @AnzuPai add `display: block;` to your `.item` class and add same `<transition-group>` tag to the top list. That worked when I tried it in the codepen. Let me know if you have some other questions.